# Angular2 handling response from service in component

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

I have a function in my service as follows:

```
   addObject(name: string, path: Array<google.maps.LatLngLiteral>, cycle: string, type: string, size: string) {
     let obj = new SurveyObjectModel(name, path, cycle, type, size);

     let body = JSON.stringify(obj);
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('auth_token') });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     console.log(body);
     console.log(headers);
     return this.http.post(this._surveyObjectURL, body, options)
     .map(this.extractData)
     .catch(this.handleError)
   }
```

Currently I am handling it in my component as follows:

```
  createExhibitionSuveyObject(data: any){

    this.exhibitionSurveyObjectService.addObject(
      data.name, data.farmer_email, 
      data.farmer_name, data.size, data.path, data.cycle, data.object_type).subscribe(

      response => this.exhibitionSurveyObjects = response,
      error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error

      ); 
  }
```

However I want to handle success and failure independently (i.e. on success I want show an alert and on failure I want to show error message).

Like in angular we had:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

```
createExhibitionSuveyObject(data: any){

    this.exhibitionSurveyObjectService.addObject(
      data.name, data.farmer_email, 
      data.farmer_name, data.size, data.path, data.cycle, data.object_type).subscribe(

      response => {this.exhibitionSurveyObjects = response; console.log("response")},
      error =>  {this.errorMessage = <any>error; console.log("error")}

      );  
  }
```

That's how I am now able to perform actions on success and error, I just didn't know the syntax.

Comment: Where do you want to handle it independently? In `addObject` or in `createExhibitionSuveyObject()`?

Comment: Wherever it is appropriate, I guess handling it in service makes more sense, right?

Comment: "Wherever it is appropriate" is your call. `createExhibitionSuveyObject` is already handling it independently. `.catch(this.handleError)` might interfere though.

Comment: Yes I got it what you mean! thanks. I didn't know the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do it inline, or you can use the ExceptionHandler object for catching global http errors.

You're pretty much already there with your inline code.  Here's an example:

```
 this.http.post(url, body, requestOptions).subscribe(
            data => {
                let j = data.json();
               console.log('here is the json!', j);
            },
            error => {
                alert('oh no');
            }
);
```

If you want to use an ExceptionHandler, then you'll need something like this:

In your bootstrap:

```
import { ExceptionHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomExceptionHandler } from './INSERT-PATH/custom-exception-handler';
```

Also in your bootstrap:

```
...
provide(ExceptionHandler, { useClass: CustomExceptionHandler })
...
```

custom-exception-handler.ts:

```
import { ExceptionHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomExceptionHandler {
    constructor() {
    }

    call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            alert('oh dear, an HTTP error occurred');
        } else { 
            alert('unhandled error');  
        }
    }
}
```

Important to note, in this example, CustomExceptionHandler will fire if the error isn't being handled inline.  So don't do the `error =>{}` bit in your HTTP call :)